# Why do float and double not print on console?

Tags: floating-point, d

```
double x = 4/10;
writeln(x);
```

=> 0

Why doesn't it print the fractal part (the part after the decimal point)?

```
double x = 4/10;
writeln(to!double(x));
```

=> 0

how to print with writeln double?

Comment: probably because `4/10` is considered as integers, with a result of 0

Comment: I like Pascal `div`, while more verbose than a symbol, it avoids the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

`4` and `10` are `int` values. The order in which things happen in your code is:

1. Do **integer** division of `4` by `10`, resulting in `0` (`int`).
2. Convert that `0` `int` to a `0` `double`.
3. Store it in `x`
4. Output `x`

To get `double` division, use:

```
double x = 4.0 / 10;
```

`4.0` is a `double` value, and so `4.0 / 10` yields a `double` result.

Answer (score 3):

`4/10` is an integer divide. The result is not converted to double until after it's been truncated to 0.

instead add `.0` to the literals:

```
double x = 4.0/10.0;
writeln(x);
```

or store the variables in doubles before dividing:

```
double a = 4;
double b = 10;
double x = a/b;
writeln(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

`4` is an integer literal. `10` is an integer literal. Hence, `4/10` is integer division, which truncates down to the nearest integer. The fact that you are now assigning this integer to a `double` does not change anything.

You need to use a double literal:

```
double x = 4.0/10;
```